# Docker. Set public ip for container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been searh 2 days before asking this question here.

I need to run container on 181.x.x.x ip and after run in `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'` and will see 181.x.x.x.

I have 2 public ips:

1. 91.x.x.x  (enp0s31f6 by ifconfig) - is default ip for all requests now.
2. 181.x.x.x (enp0s31f6:0 by ifconfig) - container must work through this ip.

What are the right way to solve my problem?

**UPDATE after 8 days of searching**

When i create task in freelance site a good man link me this article https://medium.com/@havloujian.joachim/advanced-docker-networking-outgoing-ip-921fc3090b09

**It solve my problem**.

In simple words, we set custom iptables rule for custom network instead docker auto create.

Comment: Have you tried the standard Docker Compose `ports:` option (and not manually configuring networks at all)?  That will let you publish the service on only a single interface if that’s what you need.

Comment: @david-maze Yes, single ethernet interface for single container. I try this:
`ports:

  - "181.x.x.129:60-65000:60-65000/udp"

  - "181.x.x.129:60-65000:60-65000"`
but then i run in container `curl 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'` and see 91.x.x.x ip, not 181.x.x.x 
Am i right wrote "ports" option?

Comment: You'd list the _single_ port your container listens on.